# how to check specific partition data in teradata

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I have created a table with partition on ID column`PARTITION BY RANGE_N(EmpId  BETWEEN 1  AND 10  EACH 1 );`. I want to check specific partition data.
For example partition 1 total number of rows 10, partition 2 total rows 5. is there a way to check this in teradata.

```
Partition_No  row_count
P1              10
P2               5
P3              20
```

Comment: You can refer to system-derived column PARTITION in your SQL.

Comment: @Fred - You can select and group by using <table>.PARTITION#L1?  Or whatever level of the partition is appropriate.

Comment: Yes - combined PARTITION or PARTITION#L1 etc. level (for MLPPI) can be used as column references. If the partitioning is 2-byte then the result is INTEGER or for 8-byte partitioning result will be BIGINT.

Comment: You can do something like this. `SELECT PARTITION, COUNT(*) FROM tbl GROUP BY PARTITION`